# Creating Calendar With Specific Date and Time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calendar

I need to create a Calendar with a specific date and time.

```
private void setNotification(String date, String time) {
    Log.i("log", "1");
    //Get date & time
    String[] dateArr = date.split(".");
    String[] timeArr = date.split(":");
    Log.i("log", "2");
    //Set calender to lesson's date & time
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Integer.valueOf(dateArr[2]), Integer.valueOf(dateArr[1]) - 1, Integer.valueOf(dateArr[0]), Integer.valueOf(timeArr[0]), Integer.valueOf(timeArr[1]));
    Log.i("log", "3");

    //Schedule notification
    scheduleNotification(CreateNewLesson.this, cal.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), Integer.valueOf(dateArr[0] + dateArr[1] + dateArr[2] + timeArr[0] + timeArr[1]));
}
```

The date String format is DD.MM.YYYY and the time is HH:MM, when I call the function I can see the "2" log but not the "3".

why is that?

Comment: We can only speculate why you observe the behavior you do, because the code you've presented is incomplete, and you have not included any actual sample input.  If you want an answer to the question you have posed then present a [mcve].

Comment: Use the correct tool for the task, don't parse dates yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse your date and time. Something like

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(String.format("%s %s", date, time)));
    // use cal....
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```